# Local variables - recreated

Tags: c++

I'd like to know why local variables do not get recreated if the function is recalled?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;  

void func(void)
{
    int a = 0;
    cout << &a << endl;
}


int main(void)
{
    func();
    func();
    func();
    func();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the variable `a` mapped every single time to the same memory address?

Comment: because that var is created on the stack, and by the structure of your code, that particular chunk of memory is always used/released in the exact same order each time you call the function.

Comment: Please provide a reference to where the standard requires different addresses? Then one where it guarantees using the same address.

Comment: You should look into how local variables are laid out on the stack and what is actually happening to the stack when you call a function. Then it should become clear why this might happen for such a simple example. It is not behavior that you can count on though, the address could change from call to call. Another thing to note is that if you are compiling with optimizations turned on, there might not even be function calls being made in this code.

Comment: It is not very clear what exactly the term "recreated" should entail.

Comment: Instead of `int a`, create a variable whose type is a class with a constructor that writes something to `std::cout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've demonstrated that stack variables *may* be at the same address when you call a function when the stack is in the same state.

Why not try calling the function when the stack is in a different state? For example, make it recursive:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;  

void func(int n)
{
    int a = 0;
    cout << "n=" << n << ": " << &a << endl;
    if (0 < n)
        func(n-1);
}

int main()
{
    func(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
n=5: 0x7fff519aa848
n=4: 0x7fff519aa808
n=3: 0x7fff519aa7c8
n=2: 0x7fff519aa788
n=1: 0x7fff519aa748
n=0: 0x7fff519aa708
```

As you can see, each call to `func()` has the stack in a different state, therefore the address of `a` can be different each time.

Answer (score 5):

The address of a local variable is not defined by the standard.  It may be the same from one call to the next, or it may be different.

In this particular case, with this code and on your machine and compiler, the address is most likely the same because each time `func` is called it is called from `main`, so the stack is laid out the same each time.  If you were to call some other function from `main` and then call `func`, the address would most likely be different.

This behavior cannot be depended on, however.

Answer (score 4):

The variable *is* recreated every time, but the same address is reused because… well, because why not? Every time, it is an available memory location with nothing else in it. Why not use it? If you required a different location each time, you'd eventually "run out" of memory for no reason. It's convenient for your system to re-use the same location for the same variable in the same function. If your program were more complex, you'd be likely to see less predictable behaviour, though.